# Pandas DataFrame to Reticulate results in IndexError

Tags: python, r, pandas, tidyverse, reticulate

I have a function written in Python 3.7 that returns a Pandas DataFrame. Example:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3], 'bar':['one', 'two', 'three'], 'baz':['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry']})

def returnMyDF():

    return df
```

This Python file might be called `my_dataframe.py`

Then in R, I am using the Reticulate library, along with Tidyverse, to interpolate the Pandas DataFrame into a Tibble.

The code to do this lives in `app.R` and looks like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)

use_python("C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3", required = TRUE) 
source_python("C:/the/path/to/my_dataframe.py")

df = returnMyDF()
glimpse(df)
```

Which returns the following error:

`Observations: 3
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3`

Some facts:
I found this issue in GitHub: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/101 which I thought might solve. Updated to the most recent version of Reticulate using  `devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")`

Session Info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  
LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 
LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.7.8     purrr_0.3.0     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.2     tibble_2.0.1   
[8] ggplot2_3.1.0   tidyverse_1.2.1 reticulate_1.10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.0       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.3.1     compiler_3.5.2   plyr_1.8.4       bindr_0.1.1     
[7] tools_3.5.2      lubridate_1.7.4  jsonlite_1.6     nlme_3.1-137     gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-38 
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.1      Matrix_1.2-15    cli_1.0.1        rstudioapi_0.9.0 yaml_2.2.0      
[19] haven_2.0.0      bindrcpp_0.2.2   withr_2.1.2      xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.4.0       hms_0.4.2       
[25] generics_0.0.2   grid_3.5.2       tidyselect_0.2.5 glue_1.3.0       R6_2.3.0         readxl_1.2.0    
[31] modelr_0.1.3     magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.3  scales_1.0.0     rvest_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.0
[37] colorspace_1.4-0 stringi_1.2.4    lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.5.1      crayon_1.3.4`
```

And to check if NumPy works, I can alter `my_dataframe.py` (and altering app.R appropriately)
and import a NumPy array... this causes no issues:

```
import numpy

my_array = numpy.array([42, 2.38, 42])

def returnMyArray():

    return my_array
```

My question is: how do I bring a Pandas DataFrame into whatever the R equivalent is?

Comment: well, sorry but i dont know R , can you post an expected result and just explain how do you want to get to it. Will be easier for guys with just python/pandas background

Comment: I believe this is called a tibble in R. So expected result is a tibble. Someone with an R knowledge might know a different object that reticulate + tidyverse creates.

Comment: okay then. :) it was a suggestion from my side since I do not know R.

Comment: Sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am mostly an R user and started to dabble in python but a possible solution might be to just write your python code in an `Rmarkdown`. You can write your `python` and `r` code here interchangeably- here is a great resource to get started https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/vignettes/r_markdown.html

If you are unfamiliar with r markdown I can provide more information on that.

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
#engine to run python
library(reticulate)

```



```{python}
#python code R knows this is python code because you specified 
# this above  "```{python}"

import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3], 'bar':['one', 'two', 'three'], 'baz':['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry']})

print(df)

```



```{r}
#r code 
#refer to get python objects in R code you have to type py$objectname
df2 <- py$df
class(df2)
#data.frame - python equivalent to pandas.DataFrame
```
````

Comment: Just talking through this, because I'm more Python than R, but: the reason for having an app.R file is because app.R is a shiny script. Can I move all my code from the app.R script into R Markdown and then do the above?

Comment: @kevcisme sorry I was not aware that is was for a shiny app. I don't think that it would be best to bring it into `rmarkdown`. I will see if there is a way to call pandas dataframe into an r scripts without moving to markdown.

Comment: @kevcisme in your python script can you remove `def returnMyDF():

    return df` ? I was able to call the python script without those in it and was able to use the `df` object. Also make sure the version of your reticulate is 1.11.1 or higher

Comment: Ah unfortunately not. That returnMyDF() function is what I'm using Python for. I do some modeling in Python, then output results into a Pandas dataframe, then try to pass that dataframe over to R so that I can display as a Shiny dashboard.

Comment: The `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` was just so someone could recreate the error.

Comment: @kevcisme I updated my `reticulate` package and it seems to be working with your original example. If it still does not work you could always write your `df` to a csv from python and read the csv into `R`

Answer (score 0):

For my case I was reading the data from an S3 bucket and I had the same issue. what helped for me was adding in the Python function the following snippet:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = np.array(df[c].values)
```

Hope this helps.